# Is there a way to envisage Allah, in order to better feel His presence?

Tags: salat, allah

I know that it states in the Quraan that Allah has no image or forms etc.
so when we pray on our everyday salah how can one refer God as to?  To feel His sense more. I have come across some Muslim sisters who say Allah is "NOOR" (the light) so we praise Allah in that sense to feel his energy or light entering our hearts.

I was confused a bit as to how can we even say put Allah in the "FORM" of "LIGHT".  It's still creating an image and doesn't this cause shirk in our obligatory prayers?

Further, if we even envisage God as, say, light, then what is the difference between we stating God is light and the Egyptians who worshipped the Sun as their god?

Sorry if I did ask something above my statements I am only seeking answers to find my path solely to Allah. I just want to feel Allah's presence all around me.

Comment: does this mean we take allah in the form of "LIGHT".

Comment: We shouldn't take or project Allah in any form as we know from http://legacy.quran.com/42/11  "*...There is nothing like unto Him, and He is the Hearing, the Seeing.*" But see His light as a guidance for all the creatures.

Comment: dear brother, thank you for your answers. here is the question since you referred to Light as his guidance for all creatures- so is this light - like the moon that reflects the earth at night ?or to take the sun that reflects the earth as day light as his light or to take light as the form of energy? which light do you resemble. once again we come back to the form of Light taking god as light , do we call god just by name? an object or a thing? when we resemble saying nothing? how can a human feel nothingness in his prayers to feel his creator? that's my question

Comment: You must be aware that you try to find a form of God... and this is totally in contradiction of the teachings of Islam.. we can speak of His characteristics, Him having hands etc. (according quran) but giving them a form or looks could be considered as shirk. So you may try to accept that it is Him who gives light and guidance but how His light looks like we don't know ...

Comment: Also note, that It is His guidance and your remembrance of Him that guide you to do good deeds and keep away from bad deeds! Once you don't have Him in mind you easily could commit a sin.

Comment: 1. i always remember allah
2. i am not comparing nor forming a Allah
3.like every individual who is finding god i seek answers to find how to praise god even more and above. by that i need to feel his presence always i can't take god as thing or object nor can i compare nor can i describe nor can WE FEEL ,a human basic five senses are to feel touch see hear nor taste, we are still slaves of allah and we are just at the level of minds trying to figure.

Comment: so if we say like the way you said light and guidance there is no difference in a person who praise just for the sake of praying without analyzing who god is, it's just like the people who pray or call themselves a hafiz without knowing the proper meaning behind those words and pray with  NOT real intention from the heart. the person who doesnt know arabic neither puts himself into practice properly. the population is just like this.

Comment: You write "you want to feel God" but why are you talking about a "form" as exactly this is problematic. Feeling doesn't need a form, feeling will come with knowledge of the power, the characteristics of Allah and his orders and prohibitions and when you accept them without reservations you may reach your goal.

Comment: Here is the answer i wanted. jazakallah. i guess i took the form and sense of feeling in prayers in the wrong way. the thing is i get distracted in prayers with many thoughts and these only rush through prayers.i want to focus on prayers and sense allah. this is what i was seeking for there was a sahabba that even when the enemy stabbed him he didn't move away from his prayers to allah. i wanted to strengthen my faith in god this way. which is why i would say my eman is weak and distracted.

Comment: Than I hope that was helpful, should I summarize as an answer, or just leave it? I mean the most important is that you found an answer.

Comment: yes thank you. i found an answer from that jazakallah once again :)

Comment: You just need to concentrate what you say in worship. There is nothing like allah. When you pray salah. Don't try to imagine him instead focus on what you are reciting. To do that it is important for us to know the meaning of what we recite in our salah.

Answer (score 4):

We are living humans, every one of us have a soul. What is the form of your soul? In everyday life we know things that exist, and though we do not know it's form, God said "no thing is like him". And you notice the word "thing", not "human" or such, but he said "thing". This means that whatever comes to your mind, light, human, etc., anything, God is not like it. Why? One of the reasons is that he is the creator, the almighty, who created everything, so he will not be like any of his creatures.

It is normal that a Muslim wants to know the answer to your question, but God tells us that we will not be able to know the answer, and the prophet Mohammed said to us: "think in God's qualities, not in God's nature".

Comment: Bismillah, Thank you for answering the question but this does not satisfy me. i wasn't comparing -this question implies to knowing how to feel the creator in your presence ,there was a saying of hadith stating when you pray your daily salah- PRAY IN FOCUS REMEMBERING THAT ALLAH IS WATCHING YOU< this is what i was asking brother's like you to tell me i do not want to get bored in my salah and i do not want to fear praying salah that allah will put me to hell and ask for jannah. i do not want hadith or quran texts forcing.

Comment: what i am looking for is pure love towards allah.. 
and a human being wants to know the soul is seeking answers to find it's way back to the root of it's creator..
 so how does one feel allah in his presence..
we cant just say "ALLAH HU AKBAR" LIKE A NAME OR A THING IN OUR PRAYERS?.
 it doesn't make us feel that closer to allah even. this is what i was asking.but Jazakallah

Comment: @Fathima what you are looking for is something that many people have tried buy joining some sufi orders. But we should primarily try to strengthen our faith (iman) and remember His presence in all our situations. This means do an effort to always have Him in mind: This may mean to fear Him when we were about to commit a sin and be thankful when we do good deeds!

Comment: they say god is all loving and merciful why force his slaves to pray and if they dont obey you think god should punish his own creation when he knows everything?if we pray out of fear that it means- its not the real intention from the heart to pray. just like those days where the king force his slaves to do all the work if you don't you get slashes beaten threatened and in that case they have to keep up the pace to do the work everyday in "FEAR" of going to get killed by them.. so is god the same as what Kings on earth do? i don't think this is the answer.

Comment: > Dear Sister: even in relations between humans, there is no love without obligations, obligations is the true essence of love. Can a man truly love a woman without being obliged to protect her? contain her ? if he says that he loves her , but ignoring his duties towards her, then she herself will leave him because he is having fun only, not loving her. Can a mother that loves her child leave him without feeding, cleaning, taking care of him? i do not think so. This is in the relations between us as mortals, (continue...)

Comment: 2. how about our relation with the Creator ? there must be some obligations in our relation with him to distinguish those who say that they love him from those who truly love him. So, you may look to your prayers not from the perspective of punishment, but from the perspective of love.
When I go to my prayers, I tell myself and God : here I’m , leaving my work, or sleep, or every thing I do , going to you Allah, standing before you for the time of prayers, because I love you and welling to pray to you as you told me to do. (continue...)

Comment: > And this is also essence of every other “Ebada” in Islam : Prayers, Haj, Omra, Zakat,Saum Ramadan (Fasting),  Dahyeah (in the Eid), helping others, being honest , and every other good deed you in your whole life , and this is the meaning of Aya 162, Al-An’aam Sura
 ( قل إن صلاتي و نسكي و محياي و مماتي لله رب العالمين)

But why God says he will punish us if we do not pray and do other Ebada’s ? because a human being is weak and lazy : from time to time  a human may not do what he should do . I love my work, but I do not want to go today. (continue...)

Comment: >I know I need this money for paying this important bill , but I want to have that new IPhone. 
So as in religion : I want I have to pray now, but I want to finish this movie first. NO… leave the movie and go pray, then continue the movie afterwards. But will God punish you really? God says to us that if you do the sin, you are deserving the punishment, but he may forgive you or he may not as he sees. (continue...)

Comment: > Do God want to punish us in principal ? God answer us in Aya 147, Al-Nesaa’ sura : 
“  ما يفعل الله بعذابكم إن شكرتم و آمنتم و كان الله شاكرا عليما “
Meaning: Why God will be wanting to punish you, if you were thankful and believer? and God is the most thankful and he is the all-knowing. (continue...)

Comment: >Last point : an earth King enforces his slaves for **his own benefit**, but God’s obligations are for his salves’ benefit. You pray , you go to AlJannah, but God himself do not benefit from you . and if you refused to obey, then you go to Hell , and God himself will be harmed.
As he say in Aya 97, Al-Haj Sura : 
“و من كفر فإن الله غني عن العالمين " 

Meaning: if you do not obey, then be informed that God do not need any one, either the believers or the infidels. (continue...)

Comment: At last, I hope I helped you even little, and accept my apologies for any typos and for lengthy comment.

p.s  : This is an article that may be useful to you, from Egypt’s Dar-alifta .

http://eng.dar-alifta.org/foreign/ViewArticle.aspx?ID=268&text=punishment


Peace be upon you. :)

Comment: Jazakallah for your answers, but still this helped a bit, apart from my question still how do we refer god as? ... do we say allah just as allah-a name .. i honestly am seeking to find a connection towards god . nothing much other than that. i do know allah's love and mercy i know he guides us .

Comment: @Fathima : I see, ok. Just asking to clarify you question : are you asking about how God looks like ?

Comment: @DrWael- i want to feel allah- but when we pray to feel allah how does feel him like he's watching you.im asking if we imagine allah as a form of light is that a sin? for me calling allah by name it makes no sense as you do not feel your allah. i hope your understand.

Comment: @Fathima : I think wa-Allah-a'llam it is not a sin to feel Allah as light , while knowing that this is only a feeling , not what Allah is actually is. This is a fe

Comment: ... This is a feeling not a physical , you can not ask physical question based on it, like what kind of light or  what it comes from or such.

Comment: jazakallah i appreciate.

Comment: I hope that helped even a little, God bless you .

Answer (score 0):

As SALAAMU'alaykum sister Fathima, may ALLAAH ease your affairs and pacify your heart, Aameen. Based on your question regarding connecting with ALLAAH, Most of the comments have answered your question but you were not satisfied with the answers, I had the same feelings some years back, your problem is more of OCD (waswaas)from  your THOUGHTS, I am talking from an experience, you are not alone, if someone is not careful shaytaan may use this as opportunity for someone, may ALLAAH safe us from his plots, Aameen. As I said it's your THOUGHTS to YOUR MIND, so you focus on it because its your relationship with ALLAAH Your (Religion), it's YOUR LIFE here and hereafter. Science says that what we focus on EXPANDS, if you don't change what you are looking at, what you are looking at will not change, ALLAAH said it in the Qur'aan that HE WILL NOT CHANGE OUR CONDITIONS UNLESS we change it by ourselves. So sister Fathima, pray to ALLAAH to assist you against shaytaan's plots, anytime you having this feeling, accept it and don't sit with it, don't answer, tell YOURSELF that you are feeling the presence of ALLAAH right now, tell YOURSELF you are WHOLE, say AsbunaaLLAAH wani'mal wakeel as many as you can, say Laa hawla wa laa quwwata illaa biLLAAH as many as you can. Stop giving this feeling more attention again. May ALLAAH ease your affairs and rectify your situations on time bi idhniLLAAH Ta'AALLAAH.

Answer (score -1):

Deny your and everyone energy and presence, You will feel the Devine energy , Allahu Muheetun ala kulli shaiin " everything is surrounded by Allah, inward and outward"
Inna Allaha ala kulli shaiin Qader. " everything is under the control of Allah "

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model i.e. what is on- and what is off-topic here I suggest you to take the [Tour] and check our [help]. This is answer needs elaboration see [answer]. As for the Arabic transliteration there are some mistakes: "Allahu Muheetun bi kulli shai'(in)" "()" is rather not pronounced and "Inna Allaha 'ala kulli shai'in Qaadir".

Answer (score -2):

I am not scholar and I don’t know much; I am slave of Allah.  So first say ACUDU BILAHI MINA SHAYTANI RAJIM, because this makes shaytan think who is GOD and how HE is like and stuff like that.  So sister ALLAH is NOOR as you were told and the Quran told us we will see ALLAH in paradise so pray and make duas and read the Quran to know more.

Secondly, there is difference between worship ALLAH and the Sun.  Those who worship the Sun are worshipping what ALLAH created and we as Muslims worship ALLAH, the one who created everything.  How can you compare those?  Don't say to me sorry, say to ALLAH sorry, and repent sister because you made mistake to ALLAH, not me.

And also you will feel ALLAH's presences when you pray, make dua and read the Quran, and be positive from shaytan's thoughts that makes you far from ALLAH. By the way, sister, I will advise you to read the Quran more and understand and listen to scholars.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Rather, simply reiterates the claims in the in the question without any proof :'(

Comment: You will not see Allah swt in paradise. He will always be beyond our grasp.

Comment: i didn't ask to see Allah, i wanted to feel his presence the connection of the heart knowing its lord. so i asked if the person should refer god as what during his prayers.

Comment: That is not true @Noor. Being able to see the Lord is one of the greatest blessings that the people of Paradise will have. There are Hadiths w.r.t this too.